# Chrome extension: How to append HTML to a newly created chrome tab?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, content-script

I am trying to open a new tab from the background script `background.js` and have this new tab display some text I've obtained in the background script. I am using `chrome.tabs.create({ url: "template.html" });` to create the new tab using the `template.html` file, which is just a blank HTML template:

```
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Testing</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

In `background.js`, I have a variable called `text` which contains the text to add to the new tab page, but I'm not sure how to append it.

I thought it might work on execute a script on the new tab page to append the text, however when I try to run my script `template.js` on `template.html` using `chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {file: 'template.js'});`, I get the following error:

```
Unchecked runtime.lastError while running tabs.executeScript: Cannot access contents of url "chrome-extension://*/template.html". Extension manifest must request permission to access this host.
```

Since the new tab has the URL `chrome-extensions://*/template.html` which is inaccessible to the extension.

I am not sure how else to append text or HTML to the tab page. Any help on this appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: In error it tells you that you don't have the right permission setup in your manifest.json Did you check that?

Comment: Yes, I added both `*://*/*` and `<all_urls>` to `permissions` in `manifest.json`, but it's still giving me the same error.

Comment: Do you also have the "tabs" in the beginning? Check this page if you haven't https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts

Comment: I do, I have the following permissions: `background`, `tabs`, `activeTab`, `http://*/*`, `https://*/*`, `*://*/*`, `<all_urls>`. I went a bit little overkill with my permissions to try to find the problem, but it's still not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use `chrome.tabs.executeScript` on a `chrome-extension:` page. The only valid schemes are `http` `https` `file` `ftp`.

Anyway, you don't need to. You can simply include the file you want to run in your html with a script tag. Just add the following to template.html:

```
<script src="template.js"></script>
```

Note that in extension pages such as this you have access to the full `chrome.*` APIs, so for instance you can use messaging to communicate between this page and the background page.

Comment: Thank you, I was able to include `template.js` directly into `template.html`, as you stated, to get the script running. I was then able to inject the text from `template.js` to `template.html` by sending it the text from `background.js` via a chrome API message.